# how to pass the array data to service and access in another controller (communication b/w controller)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

I am working in ionic-framework I am doing a login page when I give the username and password and click login then I am getting data from the server.

I have pushed my details that I need in a array called `var products = [];` and I am trying to set the data to service to access in another controller while log i am getting undefined value I am not sure where I went wrong some help please.

Here is my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/P6YmiLsl4mOwBEf4GN7V please let me know if some one find any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your post request with this

```
$http.post("http://aflaree.com/qrcodeservice/Service1.svc/login", loginPost)
    .success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.buildingsNameArray = response.buildings
        console.log($scope.buildingsNameArray);

        $scope.buildingsNameArray.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item.Buildingname);
            products.push(item.Buildingname);
            console.log(passData);
        })
        var passData = MyService.setData(products);
        $state.go('details');
        console.log(products);
    })
    .error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```